# Can't open photos from Canon EOS 5D Mark II (CR2 format) on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, camera-raw

I'm trying to open a CR2 file shot by a Canon EOS 5D Mark II, but it doesn't show up on Mac OS X 10.6.

When I go to file info, it shows me the Device make, Device Model, focal length, etc. but Dimensions are 0x0 and the photos doesn't show up.

Why might this be happening, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you see them in Photoloader? Or what program do you try to use?

Comment: Your link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 4):

The file is ***not*** corrupted. I downloaded it and it opens fine.

The 5D Mk II has two sRAW formats, which allows a smaller RAW file than the 22 megapixel native size. The sample photo you have linked is a larger of the two sRAW types the 5D Mk II supports, 9.9 megapixel.

Different raw processing software has [problems](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3583) converting the sRAW files though. If you have Photoshop ***CS4*** and a relatively new Camera Raw software. Camera Raw 5.5 [mac](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4577)/[win](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4578) is current, although there is a prerelease [Camera Raw 5.6](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Camera_Raw_5.6) version on Adobe Labs, you'll be able to open them.

EDIT: If you have an earlier version of Photoshop, you can use the DNG Converter ([mac](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4575)/[win](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4576)) to convert the RAW file into something you can open in an earlier version of Photoshop. However, I think you'll find if you shoot with the full resolution RAW format, it's more compatible than the sRAW formats.

EDIT2: Screenshot of the converted image:

[image]

Comment: I have CS4 and all the updates and it still doesn't open.

Comment: Did you rename the file .CR2 after you downloaded it? After I downloaded it, it was named .TIFF

Comment: FWIW, this worked fine in Lightroom for myself. Apple's own built-in RAW converter does not seem able to handle these specific RAW files.

Comment: Lightroom and Photoshop both use Adobe Camera Raw to process raw file — which processes sRAW files fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't updated your drivers. I have the 5D mark II and I had to update my drivers to get photoshop CS4 to recognize my files.